# How does Eclipse's code search functionality works?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to build a code search functionality in my product for Java classes. As a reference, I am trying to understand how code search feature works in Eclipse IDE.

Eclipse provides both File Search and Java Search feature. In Java search, it provides to search for `Method`, `Field` etc. How does it work? Any pointers to this are appreciated.

Example code search that I am referring to:
[image]

Comment: You understand that Eclipse maintains an internal representation of the source code in the workspace where it _knows_ what is methods, fields and so on?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Do you have any references which suggest that eclipse uses representation in the workspace to perform these searches?

Comment: Eclipse is open source, so you could have a look at the Eclipse sources implementing the functionality and see what it does.  Also I did a quick search and found this article introducing the JDT Java model, which might interest you.  https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html

Comment: I HAVE NO IDEA. The java-search functionality is a absolut miracle to me. I dont use it, I guess 90% of all users do use the file-search and not use the java-search.

Comment: Different kind of searches use the [`org.eclipse.search.searchResultViewPages`](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_search_searchResultViewPages.html) extension point to show their results in the _Search_ view. Via _Plug-in Search_ you can find all references to this extension point and how it is implemented by each of the different kind of searches.

Comment: Check Lucene for your use case http://www.lucenetutorial.com/basic-concepts.html Eclipse internally uses Lucene

Answer (score 0):

File search should be clear.

Java search looks for programming objects (like methods, fields, classes) and it's occurrences whose identifier is like the search string.

Eclipse presumably has imaged the Java code internally in a thing like a xml structure where the code's structure like declarations and references is stored. While searching for a specific object, it searches its declaration and usages (like assigning to a variable or passing to functions) in this imaged structure. This is also responsible for throwing error messages while coding.